# Item serializers don't work. Function never gets called

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to use the serializer attribute in an Item, just like the example in the documentation:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#declaring-a-serializer-in-the-field

The spider works without any errors, but the serialization doesn't happens, the print in the function doesn't print too. It's like the function remove_pound is never called.

```
import scrapy

def remove_pound(value):
    print('Am I a joke to you?')
    return value.replace('£', '')

class BookItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field(serializer=remove_pound)

class BookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bookspider'
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath('//ol/li')
        for i in books:
            yield BookItem(
                title=i.xpath('article/h3/a/text()').get(),
                price=i.xpath('article/div/p[@class="price_color"]/text()').get(),
            )
```

Am I using it wrong?

PS.: I know there are other ways to do it, I just want to learn to use this way.

Comment: in your code you don't show how are you creating and parsing a BookSpider object. Can you provide a little more code?

Comment: You mean a BookItem? This is a default Scrapy structure. This is literally all the code I'm running.

Comment: ok, so your function is not running because you are not calling it.  The function remove_pound is called inside BookItem. If you don't do BookItem.price it will not run remove_pound

Comment: I appreciate your answer Flavio, but I think you are missing how this should work on  Scrapy. The BookItem is a dict like object, that is meant to store data inside Scrapy. When instantiated, the item is populated inside the parse function of BookSpider. When populated the scrapy engine should (in theory) call the method in the serializer and pass the value it received as price as the function argument, that's what's not happening. **You can see that my code matches the example in the documentation**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason it doesn't work is because your XPath expression is not right. You need to use **relative** XPath:

```
price=i.xpath('./article/div/p[@class="price_color"]/text()').get()
```

**Update** It's not XPath. The serialization works only for item exporters:

> you can customize how each field value is serialized before it is
> passed to the serialization library.

So if you run this command `scrapy crawl bookspider -o BookSpider.csv` you'll get a correct (serialized) output.

Comment: That's not the reason though. **I am using a relative xpath**, `i.xpath('article/...')` produces the same result as `i.xpath('./article/...')`. Besides, my spider scrapes everything as expected, it just doesn't serialize the '£' out of the price field in the Item.